# Showing chart values differently in a stacked bar chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm implementing a stacked bar chart, and want to show values on the chart, right above each segment of a stacked bar.

To display the values, I've called `setDisplayChartValues(true)` on each `SimpleSeriesRenderer` that I add to my `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`. Problem is, the result looks like this (this is not a screenshot, but a hand-crafted mockup):

[image: illustration of the result (not a screenshot)]

I want to display "100" in blue above the blue segment of the bar, thus representing the value of the blue segment, rather than the cumulative of red and blue.

How do I do it?

PS: I looked at the [demo application](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.0.0-demo-source.zip&can=2&q=)'s "Sales stacked bar chart", and it has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of the stacked bars in AChartEngine is that each bars starts from zero. This means that the blue value in your example is displaying correctly.

However, I agree that AChartEngine should one day support the stacked bar charts the way you describe them.

Comment: cool - good to know for sure that its not something i'm missing :)